# "404 not found error" MVC model with tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying the MVC model with spring and my goal is to show the home page, I tried different ways to solve the problem but the problem still exists

Here is the error :

```
 HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.1.8
```

and here is my project structure and related files (will update the post if feather information is need )
I think the url mapping is right and there should be no problem with case sensitive

HomeController.java

```
package com.mystore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

dispatcher-serverlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mystore" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp/" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here is the project structure :
[image]

Comment: Please post code as formatted text.

Comment: I did @DaveNewton

Comment: the `/` in `.jsp/` seems strange.. (tiny, but could explain the issue)

Comment: yes I added that later , it wasn't there at first but even before I add that the error remained @xerx593

Answer (score 0):

Modify below line and after that check hope it works!!

```
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Comment: Thanks but no it doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide which URL you are using while running web page ?

Comment: yes , u mean 'http://localhost:8080/eStore/' ?   @Satyajit Bhatt

Comment: @aiden021 Try with remove eStore after / because it means you are accessing eStore request for that mapping and it doesn't exist into your controller. Try only localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/

Comment: I tried that as well but still the same , and my Application Context is set to '/eStore' but anyway I tried it and it doesn't work